# Simple forwarding of traffic on specific port to localhost on Amazon EC2

Tags: networking, nginx, ssh, amazon-ec2, tunnel

I have an Amazon EC2 instance running. I want to forward any incoming traffic on port 8000 to http://localhost:8000 where I have a Flask server listening. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure nginx proxy or haproxy to achieve that. There are many good tutorials available on Internet.
If you want to use it for development purpose, you can run Flask on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost.